# Filtering problem with data part in SharePoint Designer 2013

Tags: 2013, filter, view, data, designer

I am building a custom view based on a data source. Data source base on data from several libraries with the same content type structure. I can categorize and sort these data without problem, but when I try to apply a simple filter (from VIEW ==> OPTIONS ==> FILTER), like *Archive Date < Today*, all rows disappear from the view (none found). Same thing happens when I try to filter using any other column. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

In general when you use 'Today' in a view filter it will need to be surrounded with brackets: [Today].

Comment: The formulas are composed automatically by SPD and look correctly - have all the brackets  and all...